# Sitecore 10.2 upgrade - Some sitecore folders are not displaying

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-api

We are doing Sitecore upgrade from 9.2 to 10.2. When we reusing the same new publishing targets in upgrade, we couldn't able to see the Layout/Templates/System folders.

We can see that, if we can place the DB name in Web DB connection string.

Comment: Can you check under `View` Ribbon Menu that the check box `Hidden items` is checked?

Comment: can you please try by IISRESET

Comment: Check if item is visible in DB Browser /sitecore/admin/dbbrowser.aspx and try to clear cache /sitecore/admin/cache.aspx . From Sitecore 10.1 default items are in wwwroot\App_Data\items\master\items.master.dat so worth to check this exists too for master, core, and web folders accordingly.

Comment: @Kamil, Have created the Custom WEB DB entries in App_Data\items folder. It resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have created the Custom WEB DB entries in `/App_Data/items` and `/Sitecore Modules/items` folder like `master/web/core`. It resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

- Go to the View tab in the Content Editor.
- Check If the Option `Hidden Items` is checked.
- If not checked, check it This should work now.

This will show you the missing folders i.e. `Layout/Templates/System`

Comment: Have already tried but no luck. We have three DBs and two new targets. In Sitecore DB also, have verified the Items count. Everything same.

Comment: @Astle Did you find anything in logs?

Comment: There is no log related to this